# Why ng new app installed older version than 12 (that is now the latest)

Tags: angular

Trying to create an angular application, I dont understand how is possible with version 12 instead of version 8. Yes, ... because `ng new app` is actually creating applications in version 8.

### ng version

This is the output of `ng version`. Current angular version is `Angular: 8.2.14` but I would create an application with version `12.*`

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 14.17.3
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

### ng update @angular/cli@9

The command fails:

```
The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 33 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires ">=9.0.0 < 10", would install "13.0.0-next.15")
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.6 < 3.9", would install "4.4.3")
✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "/private/var/folders/45/63w301n97l3d90j_5n39_kpr0000gn/T/ng-h5yjfi/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

### ?

How to create angular12 application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `ng new <my-project>` you can use

```
npx @angular/cli@12 new <my-project>
```

This will create `@angular/cli` app with `12.x.x` version.

Other options:

`npx @angular/cli new <my-project>` - latest version

`npx @angular/cli@12.2.2 new <my-project>` - 12.2.2 version

Comment: What exactly did `ng new <my-project>`?

Comment: Latest two options are exactly the response I was looking for. I think answer quit wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Remove globally your old cli

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Clear the cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Install the latest version of angular cli by using the following command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```